# Find background mode iOS BLE peripheral on Windows 10

Tags: c#, ios, windows, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have been struggling a lot with BLE and a bit confused now.

I have a peripheral on iPhone in background mode. I am scanning the BLE peripheral from the Windows 10 desktop by BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher class. Now since the iPhone peripheral is in background, hence serviceid and localname are not available (ref [AppleDoc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/BestPracticesForSettingUpYourIOSDeviceAsAPeripheral/BestPracticesForSettingUpYourIOSDeviceAsAPeripheral.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH5-SW1)). Whenever I search for peripheral in background mode on windows 10 I can not find anything. I also tried setting up explicit service id filter through BluetoothLEAdvertisementFilter.Advertisement.ServiceUuids but it didn't work and the iOS peripheral is not discovered. Could anybody point me right direction whether is there any way to do it?

Is is possible to read the serviceid placed in overflow area on windows as mentioned by iOS developer docs.

> Any service UUIDs that do not fit in the allotted space are added to a special “overflow” area; they can be discovered only by an iOS device that is explicitly scanning for them. While your app is in the background, the local name is not advertised and all service UUIDs are place in the overflow area.

Comment: I have never tried to figure out how that "overflow" area works on IOS.  It may use a manufacturer advertisement instead of a service advertisement.  In order to figure this out, you might want to look for a general purpose Bluetooth LE advertisement monitor (not sure if one exists for Windows 10) and see what bytes the iOS device transmits when it is in the background.  that might allow you to reverse engineer it by varying the transmission and seeing how the byte patterns change.

Comment: You mean to say that I should log bluetooth low energy packets being advertised to reverse engineer. I was looking for software which can do this but found out they need some specific hardware dongle to be purchased. Can you suggest something on Windows/MAC/Linux which can work with current bluetooth chip inside?

Comment: You could just use your Windows 10 machine if you can write code to detect any advertisement, both manufacturer and service types, and print out the bytes.

Comment: I've read that even BLE devices needed to be paired before they'd be discoverable in Windows 10. Have you tried that first? The Win10 November update was supposed to improve BLE support but having to pair first makes it less useful...

Comment: Yes. As a matter of fact, we always ensure the device is paired. So to answer your question, it doesn't improve if BLE is paired or not. If my app is in background, I don't get service ID advertised through windows API BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher .